# JWT Secret Key as a Byte array vs String

Tags: cryptography, jwt

A lot of websites give information on how to create and sign a JWT using a byte array.

For example in C#; most places take a plain string and then convert it to UTF-8 Byte Array. Then use this byte array as the key for JWT signing.

What is the advantage of a byte array vs the string key?

Is a byte array better memory aligned so it creates a better encryption? Or is there just no difference in security?

Comment: What does this have to do with javascript?

Comment: Javascript is the basis of JSON, and therefore an integral part of JWT

Comment: @MadMyche That's not how tags work. If every transitive dependency were considered relevant, this question could have hundreds of tags.

Comment: "A lot of websites ... in C#; most places ...". You haven't shown a single example of either.

Comment: string keys are probably using some subset of ASCII characters which would not be able to produce a value with as high entropy as taking advantage of the full range of a byte.